# Android: SQLite Function Doesn't Return Valid Data

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, long-integer

OK...I'm stumped! I wrote the following code circa 13-Feb-2013 and it has worked perfectly up till a few days ago:

```
/** 
 * Get a count of all resources in the selected Alliance
 * 
 * @param db    The EWTraker db
 * @param Sector    the Sector to be accessed
 * @param Alliance  the Alliance to be accessed */
public long[] getCountAllc(SQLiteDatabase db, String Sector, String Alliance){
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.i(Constants.TAG_DBHELPER, "getCountAllc(): Sector: "+Sector);
        Log.i(Constants.TAG_DBHELPER, "getCountAllc(): Alliance: "+Alliance);
    }
    long[] mTblCountArray = new long[6];
    String[] s = new String[2];
    s[0] = Sector;
    s[1] = Alliance;
    try{
        mTblCountArray[0] = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,"TPLYS","FSECTR=? AND FANAME=?",s);
        mTblCountArray[1] = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,"TBASE","FSECTR=? AND FANAME=?",s);
        mTblCountArray[2] = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,"TBLDG","FSECTR=? AND FANAME=?",s);
        mTblCountArray[3] = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,"TTRPS","FSECTR=? AND FANAME=?",s);
        mTblCountArray[4] = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,"TINVY","FSECTR=? AND FANAME=?",s);
        mTblCountArray[5] = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,"TMSNS","FSECTR=? AND FANAME=?",s);
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
          Log.i(Constants.TAG_DBHELPER, "getCountAllc(): Alliance No. of Players: "+mTblCountArray[0]);
          Log.i(Constants.TAG_DBHELPER, "getCountAllc(): Alliance No. of Bases: "+mTblCountArray[1]);
          Log.i(Constants.TAG_DBHELPER, "getCountAllc(): Alliance No. of Buildings: "+mTblCountArray[2]);
          Log.i(Constants.TAG_DBHELPER, "getCountAllc(): Alliance No. of Troup Rows: "+mTblCountArray[3]);
          Log.i(Constants.TAG_DBHELPER, "getCountAllc(): Alliance No. of Items: "+mTblCountArray[4]);
          Log.i(Constants.TAG_DBHELPER, "getCountAllc(): Alliance No. of Missions: "+mTblCountArray[5]);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG_DBHELPER, "getCountAllc(): Exception while getting record count:");
        Log.e(Constants.TAG_DBHELPER, "getCountAllc(): Cause: "+e.getCause());
        Log.e(Constants.TAG_DBHELPER, "getCountAllc(): Message: "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mTblCountArray;
}
```

I'm at a TOTAL loss and would welcome any tip that would point me in the right direction. When completed all the numbers in the array are '0' when i know 100% that they should be greater than '0'. The arguments "Sector" and "Alliance" to the query are valid and exist in the queried tables in the database.

Thanks!

Comment: Post your queryNumEntries method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the function does work; the problem is with a particular piece of data i entered.